# r dplyr group_by values collapse and paste

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a data set that looks like this

```
Id   Subject    Date        Vitals       Value
10   John       2001-05-29  HeartRate    65
10   John       2001-05-29  HeartRate    68
10   John       2001-05-29  BP-Arterial  48
10   John       2001-05-29  PulseRate    64
34   Pete       2005-08-15  HeartRate    68
34   Pete       2005-08-15  BP-Arterial  56
10   John       2004-09-25  HeartRate    65
10   John       2004-09-25  BP-Arterial  64
10   John       2004-09-25  PulseRate    63   
34   Pete       2007-07-21  BP-Arterial  68
34   Pete       2007-07-21  PulseRate    56
```

I want to do two things,

1. group by Vitals.
2. Count the number of Vitals that were measured for each ID on a specific date `(ID + Date)` and collapse and paste these values like this below.

   Vitals      Series
   HeartRate   2,1,1
   BP-Arterial 1,1,1,1
   PulseRate   1,1,1

The value under the Series column for `HeartRate` is `2, 1, 1` because HeartRate was measured

twice for ID 10 on 2001-05-29,

once for ID 34 on 2005-08-15 and

once for ID 10 on 2004-09-24

Not sure how to collapse and paste these values using dplyr any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Count the number of Vitals that were measured for each ID on a specific date (ID + Date)

This means you need to group by all three. We can then regroup by only vitals for the final collapse:

```
dat %>% group_by(Vitals, Id, Date) %>%
    summarize(n = n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(Vitals) %>%
    summarize(Series = paste(n, collapse = ','))
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#        Vitals  Series
#        <fctr>   <chr>
# 1 BP-Arterial 1,1,1,1
# 2   HeartRate   2,1,1
# 3   PulseRate   1,1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` and `rle` i.e run-length encoding see `?rle` for more details

```
library(dplyr)

newDF = DF %>%
    group_by(Id,Date) %>%
    do(.,data.frame(Series=paste(rle(.$Vitals)$lengths,collapse=","),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)) %>%
    as.data.frame()

newDF
#  Id       Date Series
#1 10 2001-05-29  2,1,1
#2 10 2004-09-25  1,1,1
#3 34 2005-08-15    1,1
#4 34 2007-07-21    1,1
```

Comment: @Ossan, I was expecting the series created for Vitals instead of ID