# How to make vectors of unique values for specific value in other column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with a sample below:

```
     UID                                 Rat.ID    Spout      Lick.Time
1    1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active      76.9
2    1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active      77.0
3    1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active      77.1
4    1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active      77.2
5    1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active      77.3
6    1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     748.6
7    1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     748.7
8    1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     756.1
9    1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     756.4
10   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     756.6
11   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     756.9
12   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     757.1
13   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     757.3
14   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     757.4
15   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     757.6
16   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1082.9
17   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1532.4
18   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1532.7
19   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1637.6
20   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1638.3
21   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1648.8
22   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1649.0
23   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1650.2
24   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1650.3
25   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1650.4
26   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1650.5
27   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1650.7
28   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1652.6
29   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1652.7
30   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1652.9
31   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1653.5
32   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1659.0
33   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1659.4
34   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1659.6
35   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1660.3
36   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1660.8
37   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive     149.1
38   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive     150.7
39   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive     151.4
40   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive     151.5
41   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive     235.1
42   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive     860.0
43   1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1544.1
44  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active      26.2
45  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     135.1
46  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     135.3
47  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     135.7
48  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     135.9
49  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     136.1
50  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     136.2
51  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     136.3
52  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1188.2
53  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1188.9
54  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1189.5
55  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1189.6
56  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1189.7
57  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1261.4
58  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1523.3
59  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1523.4
60  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1523.5
61  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active    1790.0
62  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive     287.3
63  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive     571.0
64  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive     571.2
65  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1718.8
66  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1718.9
67  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1719.0
68  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1719.2
69  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1719.3
70  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1719.5
71  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1719.6
72  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1719.7
73  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1719.8
74  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1720.0
75  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1720.1
76  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1720.2
77  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1720.6
78  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1720.7
79  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1720.7
80  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1720.8
81  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1721.1
82  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1721.2
83  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1721.3
84  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1721.4
85  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1721.6
86  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1721.7
87  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1721.9
88  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1722.1
89  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1722.2
90  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1722.3
91  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1722.4
92  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1722.5
93  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1722.6
94  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1722.8
95  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1723.1
96  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1723.2
97  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1723.3
98  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1723.4
99  1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1723.9
100 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1724.2
101 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1724.4
102 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1724.5
103 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1724.7
104 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1724.8
105 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1724.9
106 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1725.4
107 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1725.8
108 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1725.8
109 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1725.9
110 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1726.1
111 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1726.4
112 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1726.7
113 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1726.8
114 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1726.9
115 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1727.0
116 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1727.1
117 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1727.2
118 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1727.5
119 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1727.6
120 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1727.8
121 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1727.9
122 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1728.0
123 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1728.1
124 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1728.2
125 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1728.3
126 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1728.4
127 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1728.6
128 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1728.8
129 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1728.9
130 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1729.0
131 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1729.1
132 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1729.2
133 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1729.4
134 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1729.5
135 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1729.7
136 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1729.8
137 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1729.9
138 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1730.3
139 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1730.4
140 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1730.6
141 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1730.8
142 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1731.1
143 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1731.2
144 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1731.4
145 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1731.7
146 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1731.8
147 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1731.9
148 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1732.0
149 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1732.2
150 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1732.3
151 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1732.4
152 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1732.5
153 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1732.6
154 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1732.6
155 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1732.9
156 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1736.2
157 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1736.5
158 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1741.1
159 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1741.4
160 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1741.7
161 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1741.7
162 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1742.1
163 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1742.4
164 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1743.1
165 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1743.9
166 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1744.3
167 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1744.3
168 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1744.4
169 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1744.5
170 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1744.6
171 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1744.7
172 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1745.2
173 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1745.3
174 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1745.3
175 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1746.6
176 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1746.7
177 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1746.9
178 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1747.0
179 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1747.1
180 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1747.2
181 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1747.2
182 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1749.1
183 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1749.2
184 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1749.3
185 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1749.3
186 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1749.5
187 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1749.6
188 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1750.7
189 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1750.8
190 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1750.9
191 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1751.0
192 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1751.1
193 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1751.2
194 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1751.4
195 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1751.4
196 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1751.5
197 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1753.1
198 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1753.2
199 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1753.3
200 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1753.5
201 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1753.6
202 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1753.7
203 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1753.9
204 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1754.2
205 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1754.2
206 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1755.5
207 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1755.6
208 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1756.2
209 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1759.2
210 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1759.3
211 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1759.6
212 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1759.8
213 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1760.7
214 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1760.8
215 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1760.9
216 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1761.1
217 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1762.7
218 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1762.9
219 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1763.2
220 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1766.3
221 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1767.4
222 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1767.5
223 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1767.6
224 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1767.8
225 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1767.8
226 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1768.0
227 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1768.1
228 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1769.1
229 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1769.2
230 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1769.4
231 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1769.5
232 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1771.8
233 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1775.2
234 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1775.3
235 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1776.3
236 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1776.3
237 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1776.5
238 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1776.9
239 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive    1778.9
240  1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active      85.2
241  1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active      85.6
242  1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active      85.7
243  1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active      86.8
244  1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active      86.9
245  1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     104.0
246  1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     251.5
247  1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     253.0
248  1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     257.3
249  1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     258.0
250  1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1   Active     258.4
```

I have a bit of a complicated problem in that I want to make vectors of the unique active or inactive lick times for each UID/Rat ID. I know this involves using the `subset()` and `unique()` functions, but I can not figure out the order or what I should be subsetting specifically.

Desired output:

```
UID                                  Rat.ID   Spout    Lick.Time       
1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min  LE_T_F1  Active   (76.9,77.0,77.1,etc.)
1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min  LE_T_F1  Inactive (149.0,150.7, etc.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you can create a list of `Lick.Time` for each `UID`, `Rat.ID` and `Spout`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(UID, Rat.ID, Spout) %>% 
   summarise(Lick.Time = list(unique(Lick.Time)))

#  UID                                  Rat.ID  Spout    Lick.Time  
#  <fct>                                <fct>   <fct>    <list>     
#1 1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min  LE_T_F1 Active   <dbl [36]> 
#2 1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr5_noav_30min  LE_T_F1 Inactive <dbl [7]>  
#3 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Active   <dbl [18]> 
#4 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninefr5_noav_30min LE_T_F1 Inactive <dbl [166]>
#5 1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr5_noav_30min  LE_T_F1 Active   <dbl [11]>
```

which can be done in base R by `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Lick.Time~UID+Rat.ID+Spout, df, function(x) list(unique(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `dplyr` package. Alternatively you can use `data.table` but is not as readable as `dplyr`

```
tt = read.csv('tmp.txt')
tt %>% select(UID, Lick.Time, Rat.ID, Spout) %>% 
group_by(UID, Rat.ID, Spout) %>% 
mutate(paste(as.character(Lick.Time), collapse=",")) %>% 
select(-Lick.Time) %>% distinct()
```

`tt` is your data frame. I just copy/paste into a text file.

`mutate` generate a new column alternatively as others have mentioned you can use the `summarize` command

```
tt %>% 
   group_by(UID, Rat.ID, Spout) %>% 
   summarise(Lick.Time = list(unique(Lick.Time)))
```

The answer

```
  UID                      `paste(as.character(Lick.Time), collapse = ",")`     
  <fct>                    <chr>                                                
1 1_LE_T_F1_0.001Quninefr… 76.9,77,77.1,77.2,77.3,748.6,748.7,756.1,756.4,756.6…
2 1_LE_T_F1_0.0025Quninef… 26.2,135.1,135.3,135.7,135.9,136.1,136.2,136.3,1188.…
3 1_LE_T_F1_0.005Quninefr… 85.2,85.6,85.7,86.8,86.9,104,251.5,253,257.3,258,258,…
```

I have to acknowledge I am inspired by the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143046/r-dplyr-group-by-values-collapse-and-paste)

Comment: Yes this has matched the licktimes to the UID, but it does not account for active/inactive spouts and so it doesn't make the desired output exactly. Is it possible to group by UID and Spout like this: `group_by(UID, Spout)`

Comment: @User350178 `group_by(foo, UID, Rat.ID, Spout) %>% summarize(Lick.Time = paste0(Lick.Time, collapse = ", "))` or `setDT(foo)[, .(Lick.Time = paste0(Lick.Time, collapse = ", ")), by = .(UID, Rat.ID, Spout)]` will do. `foo` is your data.

Comment: @User350178 yes it does - dplyr as intuitive as you think ! I update my response accordingly